# Exclude string from text using RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this text and I just want the connect time and the actual minutes

```
2015:05:02-08:29:52: Connect Time 11.4 Minutes.

2015:15:12-13:39:41: Connect Time 22.51 Minutes.
```

I've tried this RegEx:

```
$_ -match 'Connect Time (.*[^minutes])\n'
```

But it gives me Connect Time 11.4 Minutes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect time and minites"? Try just `Connect Time (\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: Ok, you just need `$_ -match '(?<=Connect\s+Time\s+)\d+\.\d+'` or `$_ -match '\d+\.\d+(?=\s+Minutes)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell, you can do it this way. If you want just the time you can use `Matches[1]` or if you want the full text `Connect Time 11.4` then you can use `Matches[0]`. I am doing this for a single string variable, you can probably extend it to what input you have

```
$temp -match 'Connect\s+Time\s+(\d+.\d+)'
$Matches[0] ## Outputs Connect Time 11.4
$Matches[1] ## Outputs 11.4
```

For an array you can do it like this:

```
$temp3 = "2015:05:02-08:29:52: Connect Time 11.4 Minutes.", "2015:15:12-13:39:41: Connect Time 22.51 Minutes.", "3.9"
$temp3 | %{ $found = $_ -match 'Connect\s+Time\s+(\d+.\d+)'; if($found) { Write-Host $Matches[1] } else { Write-Host "Not Found" }}

# Output
# 11.4
# 22.51
# Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement then
You may try this:

```
Connect\s+Time\s+\d+(\.\d+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxHX23/4)

It will give you :

```
Connect Time 11.4
Connect Time 22.51
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that will extract `Connect Time 11.4` and `Connect Time 22.51` from the data you provided:

```
Connect Time \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYhROp/1)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this regex :

```
^.*[Time ]([0-9\.]+)[Minute ].+$
```

Also the next time you can use the tool https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Will do next time!

Answer (score 0):

You may match 1+ digits, followed with a `.`, followed with 1+ digits *only* if the substring is followed with 0+ whitespace chars and a word "Minute":

```
$_ -match '\d+\.\d+(?=\s*Minutes)'
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5Cs*Minute%29&i=2015%3A05%3A02-08%3A29%3A52%3A%20Connect%20Time%2011.4%20Minutes.%0D%0A%0D%0A2015%3A15%3A12-13%3A39%3A41%3A%20Connect%20Time%2022.51%20Minutes.%20).

**NOTE**: The `.` must be escaped to match a literal dot.

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `(?=\s*Minutes)` - a positive lookahead that only checks if there are 0+ whitespaces and `Minutes` immediately after the last digit matched with `\d+`. If there is none, no match is returned.